# Prove $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}+1}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{100\sqrt{100}+99\sqrt{99}}<\frac{9}{10}$

Tags: inequality

What would you suggest for the following inequality?
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}+1}+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{100\sqrt{100}+99\sqrt{99}}<\frac{9}{10}$$

Thanks in advance!

Sis.

**EDIT**: Based upon the nice solution provided by Sasha, I'll try to point out a 
          possible shortcut.
We might observe and use the fact that
$$a\sqrt{a}+b\sqrt{b}\ge a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{a}$$
because 
$$(a-b)(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})\ge0$$

Comment: According to Mathematica the actual sum is approximately 0.860068, so the inequality is pretty sharp.

Comment: @JimConant try to remove N[] from Sum[] and you'll see that Mathematica actually introduced a lot of extra terms :)

Comment: @Kaster: are you claiming the Mathematica calculation is wrong?

Comment: @JimConant I thought so, but I think it's just some simplifications, like $ \frac 1{343 + 250 \sqrt 2} = \frac 1{50^{\frac 32} + 49^{\frac 32}}$. My bad.

Comment: Chris, please avoid using titles like "Interesting $X$". They are non informative and subjective.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals What?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$$
    \sum_{m=1}^{99} \frac{1}{(m+1)^{3/2} + m^{3/2}} < \sum_{m=1}^{99} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{99+1}} = \frac{9}{10}
$$
The above inequality is true since:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{1}{(m+1)^{3/2} + m^{3/2}} &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}\sqrt{m+1}} \left( \frac{m+1}{\sqrt{m}} + \frac{m}{\sqrt{m+1}} \right)^{-1} \\ &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}\sqrt{m+1}} \left( \sqrt{m} + \sqrt{m+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}} \right)^{-1} \\ &<& \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}\sqrt{m+1}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{m} + \sqrt{m+1} } \\ &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: hehe, nice (+1)